# Which Xamarin Forms Property controls the "external" name of the App on the Mobile Device?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am writing my first Xamarin Forms app. I did a couple of false starts and experiments. I now have a pretty good version, but I called it MyApp_Test3. I don't mind that as an internal name in the code, but when it installs that becomes the external name in the Apps folder and so forth. I want it to be just plain MyApp. Exactly which Property controls the installed external name of the App, and is there any other Property or similar that has to stay synchronized? I'm afraid to just hack and experiment because I am afraid of making a mess of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on iOS, it in the **BundleName** and **BundleDisplayName** in `info.plist`

on Android, it is the **Application Name** in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: And you can find them from platform-specific-projects' properties in VS. (Greetings, speed typer)

Comment: Did not work for me. I used the Properties dialog to make the change per the link from @Cfun and I see that it changed AndroidManifest.xml application android:label but the application still installs on the phone as MyApp_Test3.

Comment: Perhaps I was not clear or perhaps I am worrying about nothing. I have not yet actually built a distribution. I just have an old Android phone hooked up to VS with a USB cable. I Debug Build targeting that phone. VS installs it on the phone and starts it. The installed app and the running app are both named MyApp_Test3.

Comment: try deleting the app from the device and reinstalling

Comment: @Jason successfully deleted but the re-built app still installs as MyApp_Test3.

Comment: also check the Application Name in the Android project properties, Android Application tab

Comment: 1. With regard to the original problem: the icon is named MyApp_Test3 and in the list of open applications it appears as MyApp_Test3 but in the Apps configuration from the top bar pulldown it is correctly just MyApp. I think we have this half-solved.

Comment: 2. With regard to Application Name in the Android project properties I see only Assembly Name which is MyApp_Test3.Android and Default Namespace which is MyApp_Test3.Droid -- no Application Name.

Comment: Found it! You need also to change Label= in Activity in MainActivity.cs. Found it from the question linked by @Cfun .